# TypeScript 2 Compilation Failure in VisualStudio 2015 Update 3 Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-2015

Getting the following error when compiling TypeScript project that was working perfectly until upgrade to V2.  I have removed all references to Typings and have switched to @Types.  Only project i'm importing is @Types/node.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error TS2309  Build:An export assignment cannot be used in a module
>   with other exported elements. XXXXXXXXX  C:\Projects\XXX\XXXXXXXXX
>   \node_modules\@types\node\index.d.ts  3626

TsConfig is as follows -

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "outDir": "../wwwroot/app",
    "lib": [ "es6", "dom" ],
    "types": [ "node" ]
  },
  "exclude": [ "bin", "node_modules" ],
}
```

Seen someone else with the same error but no solution.  I'm sure it is just a simple setup or config issue somewhere as the project compiled 100% OK before the update.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your typescript version?

Comment: Latest version downloaded and installed in Visual Studio.

Comment: I believe it is Version 2.

Comment: Version is 2.0.6.0

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to help from the TS guys on GitHub we did a search for -

```
declare module "assert" { .. }
```

Should only appear once in your project.  We had an old file hiding in our wwwroot folder that once deleted resolved the issue.